# jquery onchange select option not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently my code looks like this,

```
$("#select").change(function() {
    var thes = $(this).attr('value');
    var next = $('option[:selected]').next().attr('value');
    alert(next);
});
```

and my `select` looks like this

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I tried using `alert` the variable `thes` and it pops up but when I use the variable `next` it won't. What is wrong with my code? Please help.

Comment: `.attr('value');` can be replaced with `.val()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
'option[:selected]'
```

To

```
'option:selected'
```

So:

```
$("#select").change(function() {
    var thes = $(this).attr('value');
    var next = $('option:selected').next().attr('value');
    alert(next);
});
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5SMez/)

Please note that this would give the `next()` for the last index as `undefined`. You may want to handle that appropriately.

Read more on the [`:selected` selector here](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

You missed this

```
var next = $('option:selected').next().attr('value');
```

[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7fGC/1/)